# spring integration recipient-list-router selector-expression

Tags: spring-integration

I am using recipient-list-router selector-expression, How do I match 2 strings there?
first string is coming from payload which I can fetch using payload. but second string I want to compare first with is coming from enum defined in the project.
Let's say I want to compare specific ActivityStatus enum value, say ActivityStatus.START.getStatus() with payload.getStatus()

```
<int:recipient selector-expression="@activityStatus.START.getStatus().equals(payload.getStatus())" channel="abc"/>
```

but it's giving me different errors if I try above code, also tried this but still not working,

```
<int:recipient selector-expression="#{@activityStatus).START.getStatus().equals(payload.getStatus())" channel="abc"/>
```

can you please help? I have also defined bean for ActivityStatus but no success.

Comment: Would be great if you share what exactly error you got there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you made an `enum` as a `<bean>`, but the proper solution for your SpEL expression is based on a type operator:

```
T(ActivityStatus).START.status eq payload.status
```

The second sample in your question is fully wrong by syntax.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/expressions/language-ref/types.html

Comment: Thanks Artem. I am still getting Type cannot be found 'ActivityStatus'. Failing over to the next subscriber.

Comment: You have to use a fully qualified class name, including its package. The doc I gave you really explain that...

Comment: Hi Artem, how do you write not equal to for above statement in your response?

Comment: `not eq`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/expressions/language-ref/operators.html